# How can state loss occur when using commitNowAllowingStateLoss()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitNow()) of `commitNow()` clearly states that these are synchronous calls.

I thought state loss of a `FragmentTransaction` can occur when `commit()` is called, but the transaction is not finished and the `Activity` gets recreated (which i guess is possible, since `commit()` is an async call).

I don't see how that can happen with `commitNow()`, and because of this i don't understand what is the purpose of `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()`.

I guess i'm wrong somewhere, can someone shed some light on this matter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` is called before `onResume()` and `onPostResume()`, which means you are after `onPause()` and therefore `onSaveInstanceState()`. You get `IllegalStateException: cannot execute this action after onSaveInstanceState()`  in that case.

So if you `commitNow()` in `onActivityResult()`, you'll crash.

Or at least, that's what I think happens here. I'd need to try it to verify the claim.